# C# Async (Factory) Methods & LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, constructor, factory

I am looking for a proper way to design my code. I have a list of devices a created the following way:

```
public void LoadDevices()
{
     using (XmlReader xmlRdr = new XmlTextReader(deviceConfigPath))
         deviceList = (from deviceElem in XDocument.Load(xmlRdr).Element("devices").Elements("device")
                 where (string)deviceElem.Attribute("type") == "mks247"
                 select (SmartCatDeviceBase)new mks247Device(
                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("ip"),
                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("name"),
                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("id"),
                    (bool)deviceElem.Attribute("autoconnect")
                     )).ToList();
}
```

Type-casting to the SmartCatDeviceBase is necessary as I have more different types of devices (with the same base-class) going into that list.

Now the problem is the "autoconnect": It requires the devices to open an async network connection, which should not be done in the constructor ([as Stephen Cleary states here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)).

Therefore I wanted to resort to some kind of factory-like thing:

```
private async Task<SmartCatDeviceBase> Createmks247DeviceAsync(string host, string name, string id, bool autoconnect = true)
    {
        mks247Device dev = new mks247Device(host, name, id); // Now without the autoconnect, that shouldn't be in the constructor.
        // Connect.
        if (autoconnect)
        {
            bool connected = await dev.ConnectAsync();
            // Begin to poll for data.
            dev.BeginPolling();
        }
        return dev;  
    }
```

So the questions is: How could I make that code work? Because using the *Createmks247DeviceAsync* instead of *new mks247Device()* wouldn't work in my LINQ-code:

*The type "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" cannot be converted to "SmartCatDeviceBase".*

Using the await keyword in the select statement is also not possible...

Or is there any other way how to *properly* design such code? Setting an autocorrect flag in the constructor and then connect later "from outside" seems to violate OOP: When there is an autoconnect option, I expect to object to autocreate when I set it true...

Thanks a lot in advance! Have a great new year!

Comment: Select all the tasks and then await `Task.WhenAll` to connect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the method to be async all the way.

Select all the tasks using Linq and then await `Task.WhenAll` to connect them.

```
public async Task LoadDevicesAsync() {
     using (XmlReader xmlRdr = new XmlTextReader(deviceConfigPath)) {
         var getdeviceListTasks = (from deviceElem in XDocument.Load(xmlRdr).Element("devices").Elements("device")
                 where (string)deviceElem.Attribute("type") == "mks247"
                 select Createmks247DeviceAsync(
                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("ip"),
                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("name"),
                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("id"),
                    (bool)deviceElem.Attribute("autoconnect")
                     ));
        var devices = await Task.WhenAll(getdeviceListTasks);
        deviceList = devices.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the perfect solution.